# Enable a linux service to show popup window

Tags: c, linux, centos6, init, gtk2

I developed an IP messenger using C language and I wish to share some of it's implementation details to make completely understand my problem.

1. Used GTK+-2.0 library for showing GUI windows.
2. It has a listening socket and whenever a new connection arrives then it will create a new process to serve the connection.
3. Whenever a new message arrives then it will show a GUI window to display the received message (like popup window).
4. It need root permissions to run because it uses a raw socket to send ICMP echo packets to identify the available hosts in the local network. (RAW socket requires super permissions)
5. The process is demonized , so it will run on background and show popups only when a message is arrived.
6. My machine is CentOS 6.9

And everything works perfect when i am starting this process from a terminal. But then i created a startup entry for this program to run it as a service, by adding startup script in `/etc/init.d/` directory. 
then i started my service using the service command,

```
 # service ipmsnger start
```

Now i can see the process is running by using `ps` command. but it does not shows the popup window if a message arrives. message sender gets success delivery report from the messenger. What will be the reason? What is the difference between staring a demon process from terminal by user and starting it as a startup service by system?

Comment: If the project is new better switch to `GTK+-3.x` You don't have to be root, use [Capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). For you it would be `CAP_NET_RAW`.
Your `daemon` has probably no access to `.Xauthority` of the user and probably `DISPLAY` isn't set. As which user is the daemon (init.d) run?

Comment: You might consider splitting it into a daemon running with the required elevated privileges, and then a user agent to display the messages, and have the two communicate using something like a D-Bus interface.  That would mirror how e.g. polkit works.  Basically, besides the separation of concerns, then your user agent gets the required access to `DISPLAY` and `.Xauthority` which isn't even set up yet at system startup time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your program from a terminal window, it is associated with your current login session.  This gives it the context needed to present popups in *your* GUI.

But remember that Linux is a multiuser system, supporting even multiple concurrent GUI sessions.  Each GUI belongs to one session; there isn't any sense of a one true GUI for the machine.  If you start your program as a system service then it is not connected with any particular login session, so it does not know about your GUI to present anything there.

Given that the service runs with root privilege, it might be possible for it to discover login sessions and pop up messages in them, but you do not get that for free.

I infer that the point of running your program as a service is to make it usable by people who cannot assert root privilege.  In that case, I suggest refactoring into two programs: a service that runs as root, and a client that runs without privilege.  Users are expected to run the client, as themselves, in the session where they want to receive popups.  The client registers itself with the server.  The server receives messages from the network and distributes them to registered clients for them to display.

Comment: Is there any way to attach a user session to a service? Or is it possible to start a normal daemon process with root privileges at the startup time of an unprivileged user? I cant separate it in to two programs because the socket listening process is the daemon here and it should also popup new windows when new messages arrives

Comment: @AjithcNarayanan, Using a client program as I described *is* how an unprivileged user would ordinarily interact with a service running as a different user.  If the user does not have sufficient privilege to start the service in their own session then it doesn't matter whether such startup is automated -- they don't have permission.  I don't see why you insist that the program that listens for messages must *directly* pop up windows in the GUI, as opposed to doing so via agents running in user sessions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with init.d, as systemd is nowadays more common.
I'm assuming you're running X11 and not Wayland.

Either use [CAP_NET_RAW](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)
and run your program as the user the Dialog should be displayed.

Or run the program as root, changing to the UID of the user to display while displaying it.
You also have to set `DISPLAY` which mostly is `:0` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to `unix:path=/run/user/<UID of user to display to>/bus`

---

Example with libnotify.

```
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    if (getuid() != (uid_t)1000 && setuid(1000) == -1) {
        perror("setuid");
        return -1;
    }
    if (setenv("DISPLAY", ":0", 0) == -1) {
          perror("setenv DISPLAY");
          return-1;
    } // guessing 1000 as UID
    if (setenv("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS", "unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus", 1) == -1) {
        perror("setenv DBUS");
        return-1;
    }

    notify_init ("Hello world!");
    NotifyNotification * Hello = notify_notification_new("Hello world",
            "This is an example notification.", "dialog-information");
    notify_notification_show(Hello, NULL);

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(Hello));
    notify_uninit();

    return 0;
}
```